# How can i resolve this axios problem in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, express, axios

i'm trying to create my login and registration forms in react with mysql using axios and express but when i try to confirm the button it gives me this error in the firefox console

[That's the Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmhR5.png)

That's my Backend code:

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const cors = require('cors')

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

const db = mysql.createConnection({
host: 'localhost',
user: 'root',
password: '*****',
database: '*****'
});

app.post("/reg", (req, res) => {

const username = req.body.username;
const password = req.body.password;

db.query(
    "INSERT INTO credenziali (username, password) VALUES (?,?)", 
    [username, password],
    (err, result) => {
        console.log(err);
    }
);
})

app.get("/log", (req, res) => {

const username = req.body.username;
const password = req.body.password;

db.query(
    "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?", 
    [username, password],
    (err, result) => {
        if(err){
         res.send({err: err})
         }
             if(result){
                 console.log(res);
             }else{
                 res.send({message: "Wrong username/password"})
             }
         }  
     );
  })

  app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log('Running server!')
  });
```

Frontend code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import Axios from 'axios'
import './Register.css'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Navbar from '../../Components/Navbar/Navbar'
import {Link, useHistory} from 'react-router-dom'


function Register() {
const [usernameReg, setUsernameReg] = useState("");
const [passwordReg, setPasswordReg] = useState("");

const register = () => {
    Axios.post("https://localhost:5000/reg",{
        username: usernameReg,
        password: passwordReg,
}).then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
});
}

return (
    <>
    <Navbar/>
     <Container>
      <div className="login-box1">
        <h1>Sign Up</h1>
            <div className="textbox1">
            <i class="fas fa-user-alien"></i>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" />
            </div>

            <div className="textbox1">
            <i class="fas fa-user-alien"></i>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" onChange={(e) =>{
                setUsernameReg(e.target.value)
            }}/>
            </div>

            <div className="textbox1">
            <i className="fas fa-lock"></i>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" onChange={(e) =>{
                setPasswordReg(e.target.value)
            }} />
            </div>

        <input type="button" class="btn11" value="Sign Up" onClick={register}/>
      </div>
      </Container>
  </>
)
}

export default Register

const Container = styled.div`
background: #0c0c0c;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
color: #fff;
height: 100vh;
padding: 0 1rem;
position: relative;
margin-top: -80px;

:before{
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
left: 0;
background: linear-gradient(180deg, 
    rgba(0,0,0, 0.2) 0%, 
    rgba(0,0,0, 0.6), 100%
    ),
    linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%, transparent 100%);
 }
 `
```

I tried to check if the strings match the database and they are the same, how could I fix this? thanks!!

Comment: on which port are you running your frontend and which port backend?

Comment: My backend port: 5000 and my frontend port:3000

Comment: you need to set a proxy rule for rewriting the path i believe check that.

Comment: Thanks i'm going to check it!

Comment: You make a https call to your localhost. Unless you've added ssl to your app yourself, you cannot use https. Try `http://localhost:5000/reg` and let me know if it works

Comment: Thanks for the answer Dan, at the end i solved adding Cors in my backend: `app.use(
  cors({
    origin: ["http://localhost:3000"],
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    credentials: true,
  })
);`